# Drawing a clean polyline on the map

Tags: ios, swift2, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm working on iOS app that draw polyline on the map to highlight the route user has taken. I can draw the poly line with no problem. But, the line is not a clean line that you see on Googlemap. It's a bit squiggly like handdrawn as you can see in the pic. Apology for big images as I don't know how to resize them in SO.

[image]

**How can I acheive the result like this one in the picture :**

[image]

This is my code that is responsible for drawing poly line :

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    if let location = manager.location {

        if (firstLoad) {
            firstLoad = false
            recentCoordinate = location.coordinate
            mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: Constants.MapView.Zoom, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: Constants.MapView.ViewingAngle)
        }
        else {

            mapView.animateToLocation(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude,longitude: location.coordinate.longitude))


        }
        // this is suppose to filter out noise. I don't think it's working
        let age = 0 - location.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow
        if (age > 120) {
            return;    // ignore old (cached) updates
        }
        if (location.horizontalAccuracy < 0) {
            return;   // ignore invalid updates
        }

        if (location.horizontalAccuracy <= 10){
            // this is a valid update
            // Draw route as user moves along
            path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude,
                longitude: location.coordinate.longitude))
            let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
            polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
            polyline.strokeWidth = 3
            polyline.map = mapView

            // Save the coordinates to array
            coordinateArray.append([location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude])

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538078/wrong-polyline-drawing-on-map-with-google-maps-sdk

Comment: Boy, that looks like a perfect code except that it is in Objective-C.

Comment: can you post the code that you are using?