# PolyLines not showing in google maps

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-polyline

I want show path between destination and source on google map. I am google direction api's getting route between of co-ordinates , I am getting response and set on google map but not showing on map . My code is

```
func getPolylineRoute(from source: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to destination: CLLocationCoordinate2D){

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(source.latitude),\(source.longitude)&destination=\(destination.latitude),\(destination.longitude)&sensor=true&mode=driving&key=AIzaSyAyU5txJ86b25-_l0DW-IldSKGGYqQJn3M")!

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                AppManager.dissmissHud()
            }
            else {
                do {
                    if let json : [String:Any] = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]{

                        guard let routes = json["routes"] as? NSArray else {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                AppManager.dissmissHud()
                            }
                            return
                        }

                        if (routes.count > 0) {
                            let overview_polyline = routes[0] as? NSDictionary
                            let dictPolyline = overview_polyline?["overview_polyline"] as? NSDictionary

                            let points = dictPolyline?.object(forKey: "points") as? String

                            self.showPath(polyStr: points!)

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                AppManager.dissmissHud()

                                let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: source, coordinate: destination)
                                let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, with: UIEdgeInsetsMake(75, 20, 20, 20))
                                self.vwMap!.moveCamera(update)
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                AppManager.dissmissHud()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print("error in JSONSerialization")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        AppManager.dissmissHud()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}


func drawPlyLineOnMap()  {

    let source : CLLocationCoordinate2D  =  CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Double((model?.fromAddressLatitude)!), Double((model?.fromAddressLongtitude)!))
    let destination : CLLocationCoordinate2D  =  CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Double((model?.toAddressLatitude)!), Double((model?.toAddressLongtitude)!))

    self.vwMap.clear()
    //Source pin
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    let markerImage = UIImage(named: "from_pin")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    let markerView = UIImageView(image: markerImage)
    marker.position = source
    marker.iconView = markerView
    //marker.userData = dict
    marker.map = vwMap

    //Destination pin
    let markerTo = GMSMarker()
    let markerImageTo = UIImage(named: "to_red_pin")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    let markerViewTo = UIImageView(image: markerImageTo)
    markerTo.position = destination
    // marker.userData = dict
    markerTo.iconView = markerViewTo
    markerTo.map = vwMap

    var arrAdTemp:[AddressTableModel] = []
    arrAdTemp.append(contentsOf: arrAddresses)
    arrAdTemp.removeLast()
    arrAdTemp.removeFirst()
    for obj in arrAdTemp {
        print(obj.strLatitude)
        print(obj.strLongtitude)
        let stopOver : CLLocationCoordinate2D  =  CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(obj.strLatitude, obj.strLongtitude)
        let markerStop = GMSMarker()
        let markerImageStop = UIImage(named: "to_red_pin")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        let markerViewStop = UIImageView(image: markerImageStop)
        markerStop.position = stopOver
        //marker.userData = dict
        markerStop.iconView = markerViewStop
        markerStop.map = vwMap
    }

    self.getPolylineRoute(from: source, to: destination)
}

func showPath(polyStr :String){
    let path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: polyStr)
    let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
    polyline.strokeWidth = 3.0
    polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.black
    polyline.map = vwMap // Your map view
}
```

I have tried lot of answer give below but not working for me. Please help me.

1. [1st answer tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384209/ios-google-sdk-map-cannot-create-dotted-polylines)
2. [2nd answer tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35095149/google-maps-for-ios-swift-how-to-show-entire-polyline-between-markers)
3. [3rd answer tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538078/wrong-polyline-drawing-on-map-with-google-maps-sdk)

Comment: Hi, do you have a sample image/screenshot of what you want to do? It will help a lot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42825924/7334409 check here

Comment: Please let me know how show your map. is it on full screen of any bound area

Comment: it is on full screen@VinodKumar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are setting wrong bounds so it is not showing on your map . I have tried your code it is working fine . Please change your bounds area as (0,0,0,0)

```
 func getPolylineRoute(from source: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to destination: CLLocationCoordinate2D){

        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

        let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(source.latitude),\(source.longitude)&destination=\(destination.latitude),\(destination.longitude)&sensor=true&mode=driving&key=AIzaSyAyU5txJ86b25-_l0DW-IldSKGGYqQJn3M")!

        let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                if error != nil {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    AppManager.dissmissHud()
                }
                else {
                    do {
                        if let json : [String:Any] = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]{

                            guard let routes = json["routes"] as? NSArray else {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    AppManager.dissmissHud()
                                }
                                return
                            }

                            if (routes.count > 0) {
                                let overview_polyline = routes[0] as? NSDictionary
                                let dictPolyline = overview_polyline?["overview_polyline"] as? NSDictionary

                                let points = dictPolyline?.object(forKey: "points") as? String

                                self.showPath(polyStr: points!)

                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    AppManager.dissmissHud()

                                    let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: source, coordinate: destination)
//below bounds change as 0 check it on full screen
                                    let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, with: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0))
                                    self.vwMap!.moveCamera(update)
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    AppManager.dissmissHud()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch {
                        print("error in JSONSerialization")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            AppManager.dissmissHud()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the same using this code have a look.

```
   {let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(self.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude),\(self.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)&destination=\(33.6165),\(73.0962)&key=yourKey")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        // notice that I can omit the types of data, response and error
        do{
             let json = JSON(data!)
            let errornum = json["error"]


            if (errornum == true){

            }else{
                let routes = json["routes"].array

                    if routes != nil && (routes?.count)! > 0{

                        let overViewPolyLine = routes![0]["overview_polyline"]["points"].string
                        let dict = routes![0].dictionaryValue
                        let distance = dict["legs"]?[0]["distance"]
                        _ = distance?["text"].stringValue
                        let duaration = dict["legs"]?[0]["duration"]
                        _ = duaration?["text"].stringValue
                        //dict["legs"]?["distance"]["text"].stringValue
                        print(overViewPolyLine!)
            if overViewPolyLine != nil{

                DispatchQueue.main.async() {

            self.addPolyLineWithEncodedStringInMap(encodedString: overViewPolyLine!)

                }
           }
        }
}
```

and then

```
  {
      func addPolyLineWithEncodedStringInMap(encodedString: String) {


    let path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: encodedString)!
    let polyLine = GMSPolyline(path: path)
    polyLine.strokeWidth = 5
    polyLine.strokeColor = UIColor.yellow
    polyLine.map = self.googleMapsView
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 33.6165, longitude: 73.0962)
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: center)
    marker.map = self.googleMapsView
}


func decodePolyline(encodedString: String){
    let polyline = Polyline(encodedPolyline: encodedString)
    let decodedCoordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]? = polyline.coordinates
    for coordinate in decodedCoordinates! {
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
        marker.icon = UIImage(named: "mapPin")

         marker.map = self.googleMapsView
    }
}
```